# Good websites and/or books to learn game algorithms?

Tags: algorithm

I'm interested in learning video game algorithms. (For iPhone particularly, but generally as well. I assume certain concepts are the same.) I am best off (personally) learning from a book but websites are useful too.

What has helped you learn game programming algorithms and concepts?

EDIT:

As per request, I'll clarify the types of algorithms... I was looking for any algorithms really, but I guess I was interested in (top-down view) platformer algorithms, but, now that you mention it, Seth, I do wonder about chess...

EDIT2:

I'm making this a Community Wiki due to the nature of the question.

I am interested in 2D platformer algorithms at the moment. I would like to remake an old video game (a personal favorite, publisher now defunct.)

Comment: Can you pin it down a bit (what kind of game)? The algorithms needed for Chess are substantially different from the algorithms needed for Doom.

Comment: The Stack Overflow Blog explains it, they are performing a reputation re-calculation after some changes to the algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend [Realtime Collision Detection](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/books/rtcd/) by Christer Ericson ( Director of Tools and Technology at Sony Santa Monica Studios - aka God of War ) - despite the title it covers a wider range of approaches than just collison detection including - data structures and algorithms for modern games development.

A lot of computer games coding is also simply good old-fashioned coding i.e data structures + algorithms so don't forget the two classics:
[The Art of Computer Programming by Donald Knuth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485419)
[Programming Pearls by Jon Bentley](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/)

There are also some excellent on-line R&D references on games development by many studios such as:
[Mike Acton's Blog](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/index.html)
[Insomniac's R&D Site](http://insomniacgames.com/research_dev)
[Valve's site](http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications.html)
[DICE's site](http://publications.dice.se/publications.asp?show_category=yes&which_category=Engineering)

Comment: The Valve, Insomniac, and DICE links are broken and Mike Acton's blog seems to be dead. It looks like this was a very nice set of links when this was posted though.

Answer (score 2):

There's some information at[Gamestruction](http://www.gamestruction.com/) which is a stack exchange based site, or you could ask this question there too.

You could try [GameDev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/), [DevMaster.net](http://www.devmaster.net/) or [Gamasutra](http://www.gamasutra.com/) for various game development resources.

There are various games development wikis including ones at [GameDev.net](http://wiki.gamedev.net/index.php/Main_Page) and [DevMaster.net](http://www.devmaster.net/wiki/Main_Page) and one at [GPWiki.org](http://gpwiki.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any one definitive source for game development algorithms, there are so many different ways to approach game development even within a single genre.

The best advice I can give it to learn by playing with existing technology, get a hold of some game frameworks and go through their tutorials. I don't know of many for iPhone but you could look at the Torque Game Engine or Ogre3D for PC based technologies. Microsoft's XNA Framework is also an excellent starting point for console development. Any of those will give you a good idea of the basic structure of a game project and some of the core algorithms like pathfinding, collision detection etc.

If you'd rather read book though, I always recommend the Game Programming Gems series, last I looked they had six or seven volumes but they all contain collections of articles on all aspects fo game development.

[Best of Game Programming Gems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584505710)

Comment: Thanks +1 (links for the books?)

Comment: Wow- expensive set, I guess not by computer book standards though.

Answer (score 1):

These titles are a few years old, but have updated versions at this time.  Pay attention specifically to the computational geometry content.

Andre LaMothe - "Tricks of the Windows Game Programming Gurus"
http://www.amazon.com/Andre-Lamothe/e/B000ARBG92/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_pop_1

and

Corment, Leiserson, et. al. - "Introduction to Algorithms" 
[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-Cormen/dp/0072970545/ref=ntt_at_ep_dpi_2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072970545)

Comment: Are these books original titles, or the newer editions?

Answer (score 1):

[**Artificial Intelligence in Game Design**](https://aigamedev.com/)

[**Math and Physics @ gamedev.net**](https://web.archive.org/web/20101231141742/http://www.gamedev.net/reference/list.asp?categoryid=28)

[image]

[image]